# Get an Object in an Array that has a property which is an Array that contains a matching value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an Array of Objects with a structure like this:

```
[
  {
    title: "", 
    imagePoster: "", 
    episodes: "", 
    score: "",
    genres: ["Comedy", "Drama", ...],
    description: ""
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to return an Object which contains specific value like `"Comedy"` in the `genres` Array. I've been trying a lot of ways like `for`, `filter`, `map`, `indexOf`... But, I still can't figure it out, unless I search for `["Comedy", "Drama", ...]` (i.e., the whole Array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the first element that satisfies the condition:

```
const search = "Comedy";
const found = array.find(obj => obj.genres.includes(search));
```

This also uses [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which checks if the argument, the search keyword, exists in the `genres` array of each object. And if you needed IE support, use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and check if the return value is greater than -1 instead which does exactly the same thing:

```
obj => obj.genres.indexOf(search) > -1
```

And if you wanted to return *all* objects that have a certain genre, not just the first one, filter the array with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which filters the array based on a condition:

```
const search = "Comedy";
const found = array.filter(obj => obj.genres.includes(search));
```

This will filter the array and only leave the objects that include the search keyword in their `genres` array. Again, you can swap out `includes` for the `indexOf` check, and you can always just access the first element of the filtered array if `find` is not supported on your target browsers (namely IE).

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way to get multiple elements? I could loop this I guess, but maybe there's a better solution?

Comment: It seems that the `Array.find()` example that leads off this answer is not an answer at all because it only finds the first one.  The `.filter()` solution should be featured as THE answer to the actual question asked.  The title of the question asks for "all objects".

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, I edited that in the title; that's my mistake. The first version mentioned 'an object' which I based my answer off of.

Comment: @AndrewLi - You're changing the OP's title to mean something different?  Weird.  I give up.

Comment: @jfriend00 The first revision mentioned 'an object'. Then I wasn't careful and I changed it to all, then I changed it back. I made a mistake, that's why my answer has `find` before `filter`, see the revision history of my answer and their question.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.find` & `Array.includes` are your friends. There are also polyfills for non-browsers :)

The most supported way would be to use `Array.filter` & `Array.indexOf`

```
function getMovieByGenre(genre) {
  return movies.filter(function(movie) {
    return movies.genres.indexOf(genre) >= 0
  })[0];
}

var someComedy = getMovieByGenre('Comedy');
if (someComedy) {
  // movie found
}
```

I am using the most supported code, without polyfills and ES6 features